# Counting using Hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, count, hash

I am trying to determine if a certain ID is present in my hash and if it is store the count in hash: this is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (INFILE, "parsedveronii.txt")
or die "cannot find infile";

while ($file=<INFILE>){
    @array=split "\t", $file;
    $hash{$array[1]}= ""; #the keys in my hash are subject IDS  
}

open (INFILE1, "uniqueveroniiproteins.txt")
or die "cannot find infile";

while ($file1=<INFILE>){
    @array = split "\n", $file1; #array[0] also contains subject IDs
    if (exists ($hash{$array[0]})){ #if in my hash exists $array[0], keep count of it
    $count++;
    }
    $hash{$array[1]{$count}}=$hash{$array[1]{$count}} +1;#put the count in hash
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper (\%hash);
```

for some reason it's not executing the count, any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your intention of this expression `$hash{$array[1]{$count}}`? Obviously, your `$array[1]` is not a hash.

Comment: Also, you are splitting on "\n" in the second file. Shouldn't it be "\t" again?

Comment: can you give a clear example of how the files `parsedveronii.txt` and `uniqueveroniiproteins.txt` look and what your expected output should be ?

Answer (score 3):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and EVERY script.

Your machinations in the second file loop seem a little contrived.  If you're just trying to count the subject ids, that is done a lot simpler.

The following is a cleaned up version of your code, doing what I interpret as your intention.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', "parsedveronii.txt";

my %count;
while (my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split "\t", $line;
    $count{$array[1]} = 0; #the keys in my hash are subject IDS  
}

open $fh, '<', "uniqueveroniiproteins.txt";

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split "\t", $line; #array[0] also contains subject IDs
    if (exists $count{$array[0]}) { #if in my hash exists $array[0], keep count of it
        $count{$array[0]}++;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper (\%count);
```